# Facebook login-button doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8

I got a really weird issue down here, I've been using the facebook login-button for a long time and now it doesn't work on a new web page I'm developing. Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <title>Woyou</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles16.css" type="text/css" id="css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/saved_resource" type="text/js/default.I.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

    function init() {
    var screenX = screen.width;
    var screenY = screen.height;
    var screenRes = screenX/screenY;
    screenRes = screenRes.toFixed(2);
    if (screenRes == 1.60){
    document.getElementById("css").href= "./styles/styles16.css";
    } else if (screenRes == 1.77){
    document.getElementById("css").href= "./styles/styles17.css";
    } else if (screenRes == 1.33){
    document.getElementById("css").href= "./styles/styles13.css";
    } else if (screenRes == 1.25){
    document.getElementById("css").href= "./styles/styles12.css";
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

<body onload="init();" onunload="" onkeydown="return keyDown(event);" onkeyup="return keyUp(event);" id="body" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : '275229992538227', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//www.ihaveseen.org/index.html',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth      : true,
    xfbml      : true //,  // parse XFBML
    //frictionlessRequests : true
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        alert("conex");
     } else {}
    });
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

<div class="snwbuttons" style="position: absolute; left: 70%; top: 20%; width: 5%; height: 5%; text-align: left;">
<div class="facebook-plugin" style="position: absolute; left: 5%; top: 15%; text-align: left;"><fb:login-button autologoutlink='true' perms='email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_location,user_hometown,user_online_presence,friends_online_presence'></fb:login-button></div>
</div>
```

It used to work very fine for me but I don't know why it doesn't now, I've checked some of the issues related here and tried to change the code in different ways....any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check your JavaScript code for errors. IE8 doesn't like extra ',' in the code id there is nothing after. Try removing the extra comma from:

```
xfbml      : true //,  // parse XFBML
//frictionlessRequests : true
```

Running your code through an [online lint tool](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) can help.

Comment: I have done it, that's probablly some useless garbage of soooo many tryings. By the way, I have checked the web page from another computer and it works fine, could you try in yours? I'm using IE8

Comment: Some more data, when I activate the inprivate button in IE options, it works, that tool is used to don't allow webs to use cockies and dirty stuff, any idea?

Comment: Ok! Some more data. I have cleaned the internet explorer with CCleaner and first time it connects it goes perfectly, but as soon as I close and open again, it doesn't work again. Any idea? Come guys!!!